# TextInputLayout counter to the top

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-support-design

The TextInputLayout introduces a nice counter function in the support-library version 23.1.0 - unfortunately with the floating-hint this gets very high in layout_height. 
Is there a way to bring the counter to the top ( on the same height as the floating-label? )

Comment: no - no information regarding to styling except color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't do it.

The `TextInputLayout` follows the material guide line and the counter is on the bottom.
Checking the code you can only customize these specs:

- [enable counter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setCounterEnabled(boolean)) also available with xml attribute `android.support.design:counterEnabled`
- The [counter max lenght](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setCounterMaxLength(int)) also available with xml attribute `app:counterMaxLength`. (this attr is not currently in the official doc. You can check this [post](https://plus.google.com/+JuhaniLehtim%C3%A4ki/posts/AH6tVYjiw1R))

[image]